# How to select full stops with spaces except abbreviations with regex?

Tags: regex

I want to remove dots at the end of sentences but I dont want remove dots in abbreviations. For example, I want the string:

```
Hello everyone. The U.S.A. is bigger than europe
```

to become

```
Hello everyone The U.S.A. is bigger than europe
```

I'm not that familiar with regex yet. 
So I tried with regex

```
\.\s
```

But it doesn´t work.
Can anyone help me?
Is that even possible with regex?

EDIT: This is the regex which I nedd:

```
(?<![a-zA-Z]\.[a-zA-Z])\.\s
```

Comment: In ordinary words, how would you distinguish "dots" at the end of a sentence from dots within an abbreviation?  Based on the case (uppercase versus lowercase) of the preceding letter?  Or do you have some other approach in mind?

Comment: Why `bigger` becomes `begger` and `than` becomes `then`?

Comment: @Toto sry spelling mistake

Answer (score 1):

This would work:

```
[.!?](?=\s+[^a-z]|\s*$)
```

https://regex101.com/r/agdiTH/1

Comment: Thank you. But it doesn´t work if I have more sentences?! :/

Comment: Thank you very much for your efforts. But it still doesn´t work right with me. For example this string: Hello everyone. The U.S.A. is bigger than europe.  hello. everyone. jhbj .  kjbkbk. iugig. ouhoh.     fgdfg. oioi.

Answer (score 0):

You want to match a dot and a whitespace that are not preceded with a letter-dot-letter.

You may use either of the two expressions:

```
(?<![a-zA-Z]\.[a-zA-Z])\.(?=\s)     # ASCII only version
(?<![^\W\d_]\.[^\W\d_])\.(?=\s)     # Supports all Unicode letters
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VEdhkh/2)

**Details**

- `(?<![a-zA-Z]\.[a-zA-Z])` - a negative lookbehind that fails the match if, immediately to the left of the current location, there is an ASCII letter, dot and an ASCII letter (`[^\W\d_]` matches any Unicode letter)
- `\.` - a dot
- `(?=\s)` - a whitespace should immediately follow the dot.